# Why is 月 used when speaking about anatomy?

Tags: meaning, etymology, glyph-origin, characters

One thing I've been curious about while learning Chinese is the use of 月 in many 汉字 representing anatomical features (for example, 脸， 腰， or 腿).

What is the etymology of the use of 月 as a radical?

Comment: It is not exactly 月. The two horizontal bars are actually a 点 and a 提, which in fact means 肉. It is still the standard writing in Taiwan. In mainland China, they have changed it to 月 for easier writing under the orthography of simplified Chinese

Comment: @user58955 I think I should mention in 舊字形 (old-style glyph, like in 康熙字典), the two horizontal bars are not 點 and 提. So, it may be not correct to say "actually a 点 and a 提". Anyway, in seal scripts, it's written just as 肉, and when developed to 隸書 (clerical script), they became two bars -- sometimes the second bar slanted a little -- but no standard said it should be 點提 in the old times.

Comment: @Stan Point taken. Indeed, 正字通 says 《石经》改作月，中二画连左右，与日月之月异，今俗作⺼以别之。

Comment: because the 月 look like the 肉，when the character related with flesh,It could use a 月 as radical.

Comment: Downvote because this is not contributing. Someone has already given a much better answer long before you did.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The 月字旁 was originally '肉' & not '月' - 肉 has the meaning of 肉体 meaning 'flesh' or having to do with the 'human body' so it's often seen with body parts.

## Wikipedia:

肉字旁：臺灣標準中，凡肉字旁的字，都寫作「提肉旁」即[image]，使其不會與「月字旁」相混。《字形表》中，肉字旁只在字的左旁時才寫作「提肉旁」，在字的右旁時採用首筆豎的方式與「月字旁」區分（「月字旁」在右方時，首筆為撇）。但在下方時，則「肉」與「月」首筆都作豎，兩者會相混。

Comment: I mirrored it [here](http://i.imgur.com/7whsJfg.jpg).

Comment: The Wikipedia article is not accurate. A look at http://www.edu.tw/files/site_content/M0001/mu/mua30.htm?open, http://www.edu.tw/files/site_content/M0001/sungti/as30.htm?open and following pages shows that when 肉 is written at the bottom it still starts with a slanting stroke and *is* distinct from 月.

Answer (score 5):

The distinction sometimes made between the different origins of what today (and has been so for thousands of years) is indistinguishable from 月 is entirely misguided, artificial, and continues to fail. Blatantly, the Ministry of Education tries to prescribe a somewhat boiled-down version of the 'Original Sin' (that was started during the Tang dynasty and taken up again by the editors of the Kangxi dictionary) and they *fail*. Read more about this in my lengthy answer here: https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/12455/3674.

To answer the OP more constructively in broad terms: When Clerical script developed from Seal script sometime before the First Emperor of Qin, the goal was to find a way of writing that was easier and faster. Consequently, many rounded strokes were simplified to straighter lines, many components were written with a simplified outline, and some components were given an abbreviated form when appearing as a 'side-element' (偏旁); this is why we today have such forms as 氵 for 水, 亻 for 人, 灬 for 火 and so on.

In the latter case, some components that differed in Seal script were written with the same abbreviated form as a side-element, and this happened to 月, 肉, 舟, and 丹 (and some others, it would seem) that ended up as 月. Likewise, 舌 and two other components were confounded (or unified, depending on your point of view), which is why the readings of 活, 括 etc are *not* from 舌 (活 is explained as '从水,昏声'—no mention of 舌); 入 and 人 were not distinguished; 灬 sometimes goes back to 火 and sometimes to something entirely different (as in 馬 and 熊), and so on.

Answer (score -1):

This component we Chinese called “肉月旁” in oral. The component of meals which seems like moon.