# Is there a reason the 月 radical occurs many times in body part names?

Tags: radicals

It's possible I'm reading too much into this, but there seems to be a lot of body parts which contain the 月 radical:

> [腿](http://dict.cn/%E8%85%BF) (tuǐ) = leg
>   [脚](http://dict.cn/%E8%84%9A) (jiǎo) = foot
>   [腰](http://dict.cn/%E8%85%B0) (yāo) = waist (also [腰部](http://dict.cn/%E8%85%B0%E9%83%A8) (yāobù))
>   [脸](http://dict.cn/%E8%84%B8) (liǎn) = face
>   [胸](http://dict.cn/%E8%83%B8) (xiōng) = chest
>   [股](http://dict.cn/%E8%82%A1) (gǔ) = thigh (also [大腿](http://dict.cn/%E5%A4%A7%E8%85%BF) (dàtuǐ))
>   [胳膊](http://dict.cn/%E8%83%B3%E8%86%8A) (gēbó) = arm
>   [脂肪](http://dict.cn/%E8%84%82%E8%82%AA) (zhīfáng) = body fat
>   [肝脏](http://dict.cn/%E8%82%9D%E8%84%8F) (gānzàng) = liver
>   [膀胱](http://dict.cn/%E8%86%80%E8%83%B1) (pángguāng) = bladder
>   [脖子](http://dict.cn/%E8%84%96%E5%AD%90) (bózi) = neck
>   [肚子](http://dict.cn/%E8%82%9A%E5%AD%90) (dùzi) = abdomen
>   [脑子](http://dict.cn/%E8%84%91%E5%AD%90) (nǎozi) = brain
>   [腋下](http://dict.cn/%E8%85%8B%E4%B8%8B) (yèxià) = armpit
>   [膝盖](http://dict.cn/%E8%86%9D%E7%9B%96) (xīgài) = knee
>   [肌肉](http://dict.cn/%E8%82%8C%E8%82%89) (jīròu) = muscle
>   [手腕](http://dict.cn/%E6%89%8B%E8%85%95) (shǒuwàn) = wrist
>   [肩膀](http://dict.cn/%E8%82%A9%E8%86%80) (jiānbǎng) = shoulder
>   [屁股](http://dict.cn/%E5%B1%81%E8%82%A1) (pìgu) = bottom
>   [皮肤](http://dict.cn/%E7%9A%AE%E8%82%A4) (pífū) = skin
>   [手肘](http://dict.cn/%E6%89%8B%E8%82%98) (shǒuzhǒu) = elbow

Also: [脉](http://dict.cn/%E8%84%89), [胆](http://dict.cn/%E8%83%86), [肠](http://dict.cn/%E8%82%A0), [腑](http://dict.cn/%E8%85%91), [脬](http://dict.cn/%E8%84%AC), [腱](http://dict.cn/%E8%85%B1).  You get the idea; there's lots.

**Question**: Is there a reason the 月 radical occurs many times in body part names?

There's others that don't have it, e.g., [头](http://dict.cn/%E5%A4%B4) (tóu) = head, [眼睛](http://dict.cn/%E7%9C%BC%E7%9D%9B) (yǎnjing) = eyes, [耳朵](http://dict.cn/%E8%80%B3%E6%9C%B5) (ěrduo) = ear.  Nevertheless, 月 does seem surprisingly common among body parts.

Comment: See https://chinese.stackexchange.com/a/7237/4136

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Similar questions have been asked in both [Chinese](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/7236/why-is-%E6%9C%88-used-when-speaking-about-anatomy/7237#7237) and [Japanese](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/44763/is-there-any-reason-a-lot-of-body-parts-use-the-month-moon-radical/44766#44766) StackExchange before. In summary, what appears as **月** in *printed* text is actually the graphical merger between **[⺼](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%82%89#Translingual)** (simplified form of **肉** (meat; flesh)) and 月 (moon). Traditionally, you wouldn't handwrite characters with the ⺼ radical with two horizontal lines as the inner two strokes; they would be diagonal.

The similarity in appearance is normally not a source of confusion, as the vast majority of characters which contain a ⺼ component does not have ⺼ appearing on the right, and the vast majority of characters which have a proper 月 component appears on the right, with some rare exceptions (see [this](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/27503/whats-the-differece-between-%E6%9C%98-u6718-and-%E8%84%A7-u8127/27551#27551)).

As a final note, if you wish to understand why characters are written a certain way, looking at the Simplified Chinese form is generally not helpful. **头** has undergone a very contrived simplification from the traditional **頭** (see [this](https://www.zhihu.com/question/24660661) excellent answer on Zhihu), and like 頭, characters to do with 'head' may be written with the **頁** component instead of ⺼ (e.g. **頸**, *neck*).

Comment: What is the significance of the moon? Moon and meat are somehow related??

Comment: No, they're not related; they looked similar and were eventually merged into one form in print. Some typefaces make an effort to distinguish the two (specifically, those typefaces following the Taiwan Ministry of Education rules).